# Linear system with special condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear system $$ x ^ {\prime} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & \sqrt{2}\\
\sqrt{2}& -2\\
\end{pmatrix}\circ x $$ Does the system has solution for any initial value $ x (0) = \displaystyle \binom{y_0}{x_0} $ with $ x_0, y_0 \in {\mathbb {R}} $?.

This solution is unique?

solution:

Eigenvalues ​​$ k_1 = -4 $ and $ k_2 = -1 $ and their respective eigenvectors are $ v_1 = \left(- \sqrt{2}, 1\right) $ and $ v_2 = \displaystyle \left(\dfrac {\sqrt{2}} {2}, 1\right) $.

General solution is $ \displaystyle{x (t) = c_1v_1e^{ k_1t} + c_2v_2e^{ k_2t} }$.

A clue please continue.

Comment: Please rewrite the question properly. Question seems very good.

Answer (score 0):

Now you should find the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, using the initial values $(y_0, x_0)$. Substituting $t = 0$ to the general solution, we get the following system:
$$
-\sqrt{2} c_1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} c_2 = y_0, \\
c_1 + c_2 = x_0.
$$
The solution of this system is
$$
c_1 = x_0 - \frac{2(y_0 + \sqrt{2} x_0)}{3 \sqrt{2}}, \quad 
c_2 = \frac{2(y_0 + \sqrt{2} x_0)}{3 \sqrt{2}}.
$$
This means that for any initial data $(y_0, x_0)$ there exist pair $c_1, c_2$ (and this pair is unique, of course), such that
$$
x(t) = c_1 \nu_1 e^{k_1 t} + c_2 \nu_2 e^{k_2 t}
$$
becomes a solution of your system of DE.